# What database use to store arrays of fractional numbers that give AI to fast write and read?

Tags: database, cassandra, vector-search

I need to store a lot of arrays of fractional numbers that I need to quickly write, read, and search. I need a database where I can give an array of numbers that I get from AI and get fast results from writing, reading, and searching. I want to make a fast search by embeddings where I can give embeddings and get close arrays by value or equal (as a hash).
I want to use Cassadra, but I am not sure.
I've tried to research that problem and got Apache Cassandra, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

So this will probably be closed because SO isn’t for product recommendations.  But, Vector Search is coming in Cassandra 5.0 (currently in alpha), which is likely why you’re seeing it come up while searching.

If you want to try it out now, have a look at [Astra DB](https://Astra.DataStax.com).  Its free account is very generous, and we have a lot of examples out there, like this one which is intro-level: https://youtu.be/XSEl6deX2lU

Comment: My friend recommended Apache Cassandra. I didn't know it. I've watched, and Astra DB is exactly what I needed for opportunities. Is there exactly the same thing but no cloud (I guess it's called "on promises")? And also i am from russian and i get 403

Comment: Yes, there is a self-managed aka on-premise version of it that supports vectors. See [this blog](https://www.datastax.com/blog/get-started-with-the-datastax-enterprise-7-0-developer-vector-search-preview) for more info.